# get yAxis labels as 10% of the categories of xAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to get the yAxis labels as the 10% of the categories defined in the xAxis of the chart. For example, if I have categories like [2010,2011,2012,2013,....] then the yAxis labels should come like 201.0, 201.1, 201.2, ...

Here I have basic chart with predefined categories

```
chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [1340,1590,1379,1451,1671]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: '10% of Range'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4]
    }]
}
```

How to get the yAxis plot values as the 10% of the categories of xAxis, is there any method?
Further I will receive the series and the categories from the server so categories will be numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I understand why you would want to do this, regardless, it is possible. You can use the [load event](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load) to dynamically add 10 % of the xAxis as the yAxis. Like this:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      this.yAxis[0].update({type: 'categories', categories: this.xAxis[0].categories.map(function(x) { return x/10; }), tickPositions: this.xAxis[0].categories.map(function(x) { return x/10; })}, true)
    }
  }
},
```

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
     events: {
       load: function() {
          this.yAxis[0].update({type: 'categories', categories: this.xAxis[0].categories.map(function(x) { return x/10; }), tickPositions: this.xAxis[0].categories.map(function(x) { return x/10; })}, true)
        }
      }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },
  xAxis: {
     type: 'categories',
     categories: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
    }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
    }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
    }],

});
```

```css
#container {
 min-width: 310px;
 max-width: 800px;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Working fiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/2jca44dj/

Comment: I know its weird but it is client's requirement. Anyway thanks for the answer.